# Repository pattern with Unit of work using ADO.NET in C# to authenticate user from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository, dapper

So I am using the latest version of `Dapper` and it works great for mapping my POCO classes but there are some scenarios where I need to return a DataSet instead of strongly typed classes back to my service.

Is this correct approach for repository pattern with Unit of work using ADO.NET in C# to authenticate user from database?

I am following the `UoW` pattern but I am using ADO.Net, so I am not sure if that is the correct approach. I will give the relevant classes that I am using to setup my infrastructure and Unit of Work objects:

Infrastructure class (where I am setting up my DB connection):

```
public class ConnectionFactory: IConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly string epaperconnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString;
    private MySqlConnection _myDBString;
    public IDbConnection GetMyDBConnection
    {
        get
        {
            _myDBString = new MySqlConnection(epaperconnectionString);
            return _myDBString;
        }
    }
}
```

Unit of Work class:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public UnitOfWork(IMyDBRepository mydbRepository)
    {
        MyDBRepository = mydbRepository;
    }

    void IUnitOfWork.Complete()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IMyDBRepository MyDBRepository { get; }
}
```

MyDBRepository class:

```
public sealed class MyDBRepository  : IMyDBRepository
{
    IConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;
    Helper helper = new Helper();
    
    public MyDBRepository (IConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }
    
    public async Task<DataSet> checkForUser(string useremail, StringBuilder EncPassword)
    {
        string query = string.Format("SELECT id FROM USER WHERE PASSWORD=@pwd AND Email=@emailid");              
        DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
        param.Add("@emailid", useremail.Trim());
        param.Add("@pwd", EncPassword.ToString().Trim());
        IDataReader list = await SqlMapper.ExecuteReaderAsync(_connectionFactory.GetMyDBConnection, query, param, commandType: CommandType.Text);
        DataSet dataset = helper.ConvertDataReaderToDataSet(list);
        return dataset;
    }
}
```

I am assuming here that `SqlMapper` automatically takes care of the opening and disposing the SQL connection so I am not explicitly using the technique to take care of disposing of SQL connections.

My helper ConvertDataReaderToDataSet is:

```
public DataSet ConvertDataReaderToDataSet(IDataReader data)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    int i = 0;
    while (!data.IsClosed)
    {
        ds.Tables.Add("Table" + (i + 1));
        ds.EnforceConstraints = false;
        ds.Tables[i].Load(data);
        i++;
    }                    

    return ds;
}
```

My Service class looks like:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    #region CTOR
    public MyService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
    
    public async Task<result> checkForUserService(string useremail, StringBuilder EncPassword)
    {
        var obj = await _unitOfWork.MyDBRepository.checkForUser(useremail, EncPassword);
        if (obj.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            //Incorrect username/password
            result.flag=false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Do stuff
            result.flag=true;
        }
    }
}
```

I call the above service from a MVC project (4.6.1):

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    IMyService _myService;
    ISubscriptionService _subscriptionService;
    
    public TestController()
    {

    }

    public TestController(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }
    
    // GET: check user test
    public ActionResult checkUserTest()
    {
        string EmailId = "myemail@blah.com";
        StringBuilder EncPassword = new StringBuilder();
        //Using a standard hashing algorithm 
        EncPassword.Append("encodedpassword");
        var resultData = _myService.checkForUserService(EmailId, EncPassword).Result;
        if(resultData.flag)
        {
            //Set session variable here
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["loggedinemail"] = resultData.EmailId;
        }
        string jsonDataSet = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultData);
        return Json(jsonDataSet, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    } 
}
```

I wanted any suggestions/design changes that I can do in order to use the repository pattern with Unit of Work with Dapper correctly. It is working for me at the moment but I am not sure if the implementation of the repository pattern is done correctly with Unit of work since I am using ADO.NET.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and title your question for what the code presented is to accomplish.

Comment: @greybeard I have updated the title to be more descriptive as required

Comment: _"there are some scenarios where I need to return a DataSet instead of strongly typed classes"_ Why your data set's columns not be expressed as a concrete class?

Comment: @RahulSharma Why do you use custom encoding algorithm against password? Why don't you use one of standard hashing algorithm?

Comment: @Flater I can do that part also but that would require a lot of rework at my end because of the original implementation done like this. We are getting the `DataSet` back from the database to perform manipulations on it in `C#` before mapping them to a class.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thank you for your concern but I might have mislead the readers on that part. I am using a standard hashing algorithm for this purpose. Sorry my bad there.

Comment: @RahulSharma: "it exists" shouldn't be the main reason why you choose to take a provably inefficient approach.

Comment: @Flater I did not get your point. Can you please elaborate here?

Comment: Please do not edit your question with new code now that there's an answer. Submit a new question instead.

Comment: @Reinderien I have submitted a new question for the same: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/255835/is-this-correct-way-to-setup-db-infrastructure-with-repository-pattern-and-dappe

Answer (score 5):

### Side-effects

On its own, this:

```
private MySqlConnection _myDBString;
public IDbConnection GetMyDBConnection
{
    get
    {
        _myDBString = new MySqlConnection(epaperconnectionString);
        return _myDBString;
    }
}
```

is a deeply bad idea. Getters should usually be trusted to have no side-effects that mutate the class.

The only exception to this I would make is if you're using `_myDBString` as a cache, which you're not. To do this you would check to see if that member has already been set, and if so, return the member without a new call to `MySqlConnection`.

Even so, such caching is not the right way to go about reducing connection load; instead use an actual connection pool. For more information on this approach a reasonable starting point is the [MySQL Connector Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-pooling.html).

Also `_myDBString` is the wrong name. It's *not* a connection string; it's a *connection*.

Comment: The ID is used: `["loggedinemail"] = resultData.EmailId;`. But the code is needlessly overcomplicated, which is why it is almost impossible to figure out what it exactly does; yet in its core it is really simple.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I didn't catch that; thanks.

Comment: @Reinderien Thank you very much for the review. Could you give me an example of how the correctly implement the above connection initialization?

Comment: @Reinderien Is there any example that you can direct me to handle this properly? Thanks

Comment: @RahulSharma Sure; I linked to the MySQL documentation on connection pooling.

Comment: @Reinderien Thank you very much. I shall take a look into it. Other than that, is there any suggestions that you can give on the above code structure Or does the implementation look right to you?

Comment: @Reinderien I was investigation into this and apparently, connection pooling is set by default in ADO.NET: `To enable this connection pooling in asp.net we don’t need to do anything by default connection pooling is enabled in ADO.NET. Unless we manually disable the connection pooling, the pooler will optimize the connections when they are opened and closed in our application.` https://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2016/07/connection-pooling-in-aspnet-using-csharp-with-example.html. So my question would be here is how to handle to properly handle the connection string in this class?

Comment: In a method like your check-for-user, do not call `_connectionFactory.GetMyDBConnection` as you are. Instead, tell ADO to open a new connection, and put it in a `using` clause that restricts the scope of the connection lease to your query.

Answer (score 4):

Some quick remarks:

- `epaperconnectionString` doesn't follow the proper naming conventions for compound words. Also: why wouldn't you store all your configuration settings in a dedicated class? (I'm not a fan of seeing `ConfigurationManager` all over the place: if you ever need to change a setting's name you need to look in multiple places, whereas it would be a single location if you'd centralized all those settings.)
- `Helper` is too generic a class name. So is `MyDBRepository`. So is `resultData`. Don't get me started on `obj`.
- `list` isn't the correct name for an `IDataReader`.
- `checkForUser` doesn't follow the naming guidelines. Ditto `checkForUserService` (that method name is simply baffling, BTW).
- What is `result`? Why doesn't it follow the naming conventions? Why does it have a property `flag` that also doesn't follow naming conventions?

---

But mostly this looks to me like a solution in search of a problem. Why work with `DynamicParameters` and `SqlMapper` and `IDataReader` etc. when you could just as easily use "proper" Dapper code, return a class or an `int` (whatever type "id" is) and then convert that to a `DataSet`?

And for what? You end up with `var obj = await _unitOfWork.MyDBRepository.checkForUser(useremail, EncPassword);` and then based on `obj.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0` you set `result.flag` to `true` or `false`. And so on. I see a massive amount of code that pointlessly uses a `DataSet` etc. for what (as far as I can deduct) a ridiculously simple piece of logic: you need the ID belonging to a provided email address.

I can throw away 90% of your code (including the overkill of a unit of work and a repository) and replace it with a simple service class that contains a single method with a simple Dapper query that returns an `int?` (or whatever type that ID is). Why did you overengineer it in the way you did?

---

You say:

> there are some scenarios where I need to return a DataSet instead of strongly typed classes

Nothing in the code you provide here proves this.

Comment: Thank you for review on this. I have understood the naming convention and I will do the changes proposed by you. Can you give me an example of getting the configuration in the correct way. I encounter the `object not set to an instance of an object` error on this line in: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString;`. I am working with `DynamicParameters`, `SqlMapper` because they are integral part of `Dapper` so I need them in my code. You are right about the overengineer part but this is sample piece from a huge library of methods. I wanted a service based model.

Comment: Basically, all the business logic goes into the Service class. The database class (repository) is only for performing CRUD operations. I could have made it into all a simple service class as you proposed but then it would have been cumbersome to put business logic there. This is a small sample from a huge codebase. All I wanted to know is if the repository pattern with unit of work is properly being followed with all resource management being done (in the repository class). Thanks again.

Comment: Also for `there are some scenarios where I need to return a DataSet instead of strongly typed classes`: I have some scenarios where I need to perform manipulations from the data returned back from the database before finally sending it out to the client. This can be done using a `DTO` if I were using a service based web api but since this a .NET Standard libary project, I am left with the option to get the dataset and then perform manipulation on it before mapping to the c# class. If there is a better and efficient way to do it, then I would like to know.

Comment: I have used Dapper countless times and the only time I have used `DynamicParameters` was in one exceptional case, and I have never used its `SqlMapper`. Those things are there for exceptional cases, and your code isn't that.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from having a "DAO" class that still uses DTOs. So what if you need to do data manipulation post-db retrieval? Just return a "raw"/"simplified" DTO and transform that to a more complex DTO in the class with your business logic. A `DataSet` is IMHO absolutely the wrong thing to use here, not in the least because you lose so much and gain nothing. "since this a .NET Standard library project": why would this be relevant?

Comment: I have used the Unit Of Work / Repository structure one time at my current place of employment, and each time I have to make adjustments in that code I cringe and curse myself for doing it. It adds pointless overhead and it requires you to write tons of duplicate code that only gets in the way of what you need to do.